# CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent not present in MingW

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I'm building the QT 5.2.1 Open Source using MingW with gcc 4.8.1 (latest available installation) on Windows 7. After fixing several issues, Inow have the problem that I get an error telling me that `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent` doesn't seem to be present.

I added this to qwindowsclipboard.cpp

```
#ifndef CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent
WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(HANDLE,PBOOL);
#endif
```

So now it comopuiles but doesn't link.

```
D:\src\ext\c\qt-src-5.2.1\qtbase\src\plugins\platforms\windows/qwindowsclipboard.cpp:194: undefined reference to `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent(void*, int*)@8'
```

I also updated the makefile and added kernel32.lib to the build, because it was missing- According to MSDN it should be there. When I searched through the MinGW libraries I can also see that there is a symbol for this function in libkernel32.a, so I would think it should be there, but when I put this librry in the commandline it doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: It might be safer to use the mingw that comes bundled with Qt itself. At least that's what I'd try first. Download the Qt 5.2.1 mingw build, when installing select to install the sources as well, then attempt a clean, out-of-source configure and build. In a new folder, call `C:\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\Src\configure.exe -debug-and-release` (adjust to match your install path). Then call `gmake` (or `make`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to compile the source code successfully. This, and several other problems, are due to the fact that QT no longer supports MingW32 and you have to use MingW64 instead. At first it was unclear to me that this can still build 32 bit applications because of the name, but it works.